# How to call a batch from a trigger?

Tags: apex

I have to call a batch from a trigger.

How can I call a batch from a trigger.

I tried to call batch as a normal method call but it is not working

Comment: have you tried anything? If you just add the execute code then it will work without any issue `Database.executeBatch(new mybatchClass())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @future annotation above method

Comment: YogeshGupta we can execute batch without @future method as well

Comment: I think its an async call so we have to use @future ? is it true ?

Comment: @YogeshGupta future is an async call as well. There is no need to use future to execute a batch from a trigger so this answer is technically not correct. In addition, executing batches from triggers can be problematic if you are not checking for already queued batches. If possible you can simply call the execute method with the records in the trigger by `mybatchclass  b = New mybatchclass(); b.start(null,[Select Id, ..other fields.. From xxx Where ID IN :trigger.new);` if done in an after trigger thus executing the core functionality if possible

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke executebatch with batch class instance and scope

```
    database.executebatch(new BatchClassName(),200);
```

from trigger it will work.

Bur beware of governor limits as batch processing is an asynchronous job. you can hit your governor limits

Answer (score 0):

I can run easily my batch class from the trigger here is the code of the trigger:-

> trigger UpdateStateCountryCode on Lead (before insert, before update) {

```
if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    System.debug('Hello from IsBefore');
    for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {              
        myBatchClass b = New myBatchClass();
        database.executebatch(b,1); 
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.